# UITableViewCell doesn't get deselected when swiping back quickly

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I've now updated three of my apps to iOS 7, but in all three, despite them not sharing any code, I have the problem where if the user swipes to go back in the navigation controller (rather than tap the back button) quickly, the cell will remain in its selected state.

For the three apps, one uses custom cells created programmatically, another uses custom cells created in a storyboard and the third uses default cells in a very basic subclass of UITableView, also in a storyboard. In all three cases, the cells don't deselect by themselves. If the user swipes slowly, or hits the back button, they deselect as normal.

This is only happening in my iOS 7 apps, Apple's own apps and third party apps upgraded for iOS 7 all seem to be behaving normally (albeit with slight differences in how quickly the cells gets deselected).

There must be something I'm doing wrong, but I'm not sure what?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I'm dealing with the same problem right now. The [UICatalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007710)-sample from Apple seems to bring the dirty solution.

It really doesn't make me happy at all. As mentioned before it uses `[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:tableSelection animated:NO];` to deselect the currently selected row.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // this UIViewController is about to re-appear, make sure we remove the current selection in our table view
    NSIndexPath *tableSelection = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:tableSelection animated:NO];

    // some over view controller could have changed our nav bar tint color, so reset it here
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
}
```

*I have to mention the sample code may not be <del>iOS 7</del> <del>iOS 8</del> <del>iOS 9</del> iOS 10-ready*

---

Something which really confuses me is the [UITableViewController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> When the table view is about to appear the first time it’s loaded, the
>   table-view controller reloads the table view’s data. **It also clears
>   its selection (with or without animation, depending on the request)
>   every time the table view is displayed.** The `UITableViewController`
>   class implements this in the superclass method `viewWillAppear:`. You
>   can disable this behavior by changing the value in the
>   `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear` property.

This is exactly the behavior I expect… but it does not seem to work. Neither for you nor for me. We really have to use the "dirty" solution and do it on our own.

Comment: Glad I'm not the only one who thinks so, I've filed a bug.

Comment: Sadly this solution doesn't work for me on iOS 7.0.4.

Comment: Same here, I have the problem on iOS 7.1 but this won't solve it

Comment: @ArieLitovsky I recently used this workaround I described above and it worked for me. Is there an error? An exception? Something else you can tell us?

Comment: I can't believe this is still an issue with iOS 8.

Comment: I can't believe this is still an issue with iOS 9.

Comment: Can anyone tell what's causing this? Because clearly it's not broken everywhere... I couldn't reproduce it in a test project, but I also cannot find the source of the problem in my app where it occurs...

Comment: @CodeStage No, but it's reproducable when changing the velocity of your Swipe and when/where you're lifting your finger. I just tested it again: If you swipe back quickly it won't work in most cases. If you'll do a gentle swipe it'll work in most cases.

Comment: @FabioPoloni , If the problem appears, it will appear every time you swipe back to the tableViewController, until the tableViewController is deallocated.

Comment: @DawnSong I've tried this several times in different applications with different velocities. You can believe me, that it *really* depends on velocity and other factors. The issue is really weird. But I wonder what you want to say with *"… until the `UITableViewController` is deallocated"*? I mean, *after deallocation* the instance is away. gone. forever.

Comment: Once the problem is triggered by slow swipe, it will appear again without relation to velocity until the tableViewController is recreated.

Comment: @DawnSong That's an interesting observation. Let's see wether iOS 10 will fix this or if we'll wait for another year.

Comment: obviously, this issue still exists

Comment: @JerryTang I can't believe you broke the run we had for a few years. Let's try to make it better for iOS 11 and upward

Comment: I can't believe this is still an issue with iOS 10.

Comment: I can't believe this is still an issue with iOS 11

Comment: I can't believe this is still an issue with iOS 11.4.1.

Answer (score 54):

This worked best for me:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:animated];
}
```

I even got a much better unselect fading while I was swiping back slowly.

Comment: Worked on 7.1 as well

Comment: What do you do when a user half swipes back, but then cancels the pan gesture?

Comment: I address the "half swipes, then cancels" in my other answer.

Comment: Setting `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear` to `YES` or `NO` didn't change anything for me on iOS 9, so I left it out. Nice solution!

Comment: @edelaney05, I wouldn't do anything - not worth it. If you look at the  iOS Settings app, it has the same issue.

Answer (score 19):

Fabio's answer works well but doesn't give the right look if the user swipes just a little bit and then changes their mind. In order to get that case right you need to save the selected index path and reset it when necessary.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.savedSelectedIndexPath = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    if (self.savedSelectedIndexPath) {
        [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:self.savedSelectedIndexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    }
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.savedSelectedIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow;

    if (self.savedSelectedIndexPath) {
        [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:self.savedSelectedIndexPath animated:YES];
    }
}
```

If using a UITableViewController, make sure to disable the built-in clearing:

```
self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
```

and add the property for savedSelectedIndexPath:

```
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSIndexPath *savedSelectedIndexPath;
```

If you need to do this in a few different classes it might make sense to split it out in a helper, for example like I did in this gist: https://gist.github.com/rhult/46ee6c4e8a862a8e66d4

Comment: I'm using similar solution, but I select row without animation just before calling deselect with animation.

Comment: I can't believe this isn't the default implementation for UITableViewController...

Comment: Works absolutely perfect on iOS 9.1

Comment: I can't believe this is necessary! Works like a charm though.

Comment: works perfectly on iOS 9, still wonder why we have to implement this on our own tho

Answer (score 9):

This solution animates the row deselection along with the transition coordinator (for a user-driven VC dismiss) and re-applies the selection if the user cancels the transition. Adapted from a solution by [Caleb Davenport](https://gist.github.com/calebd/e6246d416b12c52c7fa5) in Swift. Only tested on iOS 9. Tested as working with both user driven (swipe) transition and the old-style "Back" button tap.

In the `UITableViewController` subclass:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // Workaround. clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear is unreliable for user-driven (swipe) VC dismiss
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow;
    if (indexPath && self.transitionCoordinator) {
        [self.transitionCoordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext>  _Nonnull context) {
            [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:animated];
        } completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext>  _Nonnull context) {
            if ([context isCancelled]) {
                [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't upvote this enough. Thank you! For everyone else - this is a much better + more elegant solution than most presented here.

Answer (score 7):

After running into this myself today I found out that this apparently is a fairly well-known problem with UITableView, its support for interactive navigation transitions is slightly broken. The folks behind Castro have posted an excellent analysis and solution to this: http://blog.supertop.co/post/80781694515/viewmightappear

I decided to use their solution which also considers cancelled transitions:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSIndexPath *selectedRowIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    if (selectedRowIndexPath) {
        [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:selectedRowIndexPath animated:YES];
        [[self transitionCoordinator] notifyWhenInteractionEndsUsingBlock:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
            if ([context isCancelled]) {
                [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:selectedRowIndexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try to set

```
self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = YES;
```

in a UITableViewController or

```
[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:NO];
```

in viewWillAppear, maybe before calling [super viewWillAppear:animated];
If your UItableView is **not** inside an UITableViewController you must deselect the cells manually:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES]; 
}
```

Comment: `self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = YES;` doesn't work, though I expected that because that's default anyway. `[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:animated];` inside `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` (after calling `super`) does work, however I'm confused why this is necessary. Shouldn't the table view controller be doing that when I call `super` in `viewWillAppear:`? How come it's only affecting the dragging mode and not the standard 'tap on back button' one?

Comment: @falsecrypt `[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];` worked in my project though, like @Robert, I'm also confused as to why this is necessary.  Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Simple Swift 3/4 Answer:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow != nil {
        self.tableView.deselectRow(at: tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow! as IndexPath, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Bless your heart for updating for Swift 3. 

Answer (score 2):

I'm using

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

at the end of method

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Like this:

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    //doing something according to selected cell...

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

`[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];`

code in

`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method`

Answer (score 1):

I've found a very simple solution to this problem that just makes the default behavior work as it should. I wasn't satisfied with the solutions involving `deselectRowAtIndexPath` since the resulting visual effect was slightly different.

All you have to do in order to prevent this weird behavior is to reload the table when the view is displayed:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: The reloadData call could be very expensive in some situations (think of a large database) so it's not the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

[Codestage answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34989883/6051635), in Swift 3. `notifyWhenInteractionEnds` is deprecated.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        self.transitionCoordinator?.notifyWhenInteractionChanges { (context) in
            if context.isCancelled {
                self.tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably not calling the super view's viewWillAppear method ([super viewWillAppear:animated];).
When you do this and the UITableViewController's parameter clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear is YES then the cells will be deselected on viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Rhult](https://stackoverflow.com/users/214401/rhult)'s code, I made a few changes.

This implementation allow user to cancel swipe back and still keep selected for future swipe back deselect animation

```
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSIndexPath *savedSelectedIndexPath;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
}

-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   [super viewDidAppear:animated];
   self.savedSelectedIndexPath = nil;
}

-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
   [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
   if (self.savedSelectedIndexPath && ![self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]) {
       [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:self.savedSelectedIndexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
   } else {
      self.savedSelectedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Rhult's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25820919/3947107) works perfectly on iOS 9.2. This is the implementation in Swift:

Declare a variable in your `MasterViewController` to save the IndexPath:

```
var savedSelectedIndexPath: NSIndexPath?
```

Then you can put the code in an extension for clarity:

```
extension MasterViewController {
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.savedSelectedIndexPath = nil
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        if let indexPath = self.savedSelectedIndexPath {
            self.tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .None)
        }
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.savedSelectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        if let indexPath = self.savedSelectedIndexPath {
            self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Codestage provided by far the best looking answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34989883/6051635), so I decided to convert it into Swift 2.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)

        let selectedRowIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        if ((selectedRowIndexPath) != nil) {
            self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(selectedRowIndexPath!, animated: true)
            self.transitionCoordinator()?.notifyWhenInteractionEndsUsingBlock({ context in
                if (context.isCancelled()) {
                    self.tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(selectedRowIndexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For swift

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else{
        return
    }
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}
```